# How to train Tensor Flow imageclassifier in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train the existing classifier which I have downloaded from 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models

TensorFlow Image Recognition.The reason is when I put an image of traffic sign, e.g stop sign and other road sign it just says its a street sign instead of its right name like stop for stop sign.

How can I add up my data set of road signs with the existing TensorFlow data set that is using by this classifier?

Comment: Are you using a pretrained model? If you are training the model yourself, are the targets labelled with the street sign name?

Comment: Yes its a pretrained model by tensor flow for image recognization I have my folders of streets sign with image but i need to know how can i train the pretrained model which tensor flow is using.

Comment: You cannot use a pretrained model off-the-shelf to predict labels which were not present in the original classification. However, you can use the pretrained model and fix those variables while adding additional layers on top. The additional layers with trainable parameters will learn your task while leveraging the information in the pretrained model. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Exactly!I want image recognition of tensor flow also i want to add my own category to be added in it.So that i can check my categories and tensor-flow data-set too.I am using windows.